# C beginner not terminating program

Tags: c, sum, termination

I'm a beginner in C and I received the task to write a simple sum program, where I have to use my own atoi function.

The behavior is really strange: 
sum 1 -> works fine, it writes "the sum is 1"
sum 1 2 -> it doesn't terminate 
sum -1 -2 -> it only writes the first number, if I use more than 2 it doesn't terminate

This are some parts of the code, I suppose that the error is in the mi_atoi, cause it works normally if I use the library function:

```
unsigned int char2int(char c)
{
    return c-'0';
}

int mi_atoi(char *s)
{
    int x = 0;
    if (s[0] == 45) {
        for (i = 1; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            x = x*10 - char2int(s[i]);
        }
    }
    else { 
        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            x = x*10 + char2int(s[i]);
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

And here the main (the function esNumero just checks if the argument is a number and it works fine):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[80];
    int suma = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (esNumero (argv[i]) == 0) {
            sprintf (buf, "El parametro \"%s\" no es un numero\n", argv[i]);
            write (1, buf, strlen (buf));
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            suma = suma + mi_atoi(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    sprintf (buf, "La suma es %d\n", suma);
    write (1, buf, strlen (buf));

    return 0;
}
```

Could you please have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing we can see you are doing wrong  is the indentation.

Comment: What is the use of write function here ?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and **use the debugger**  `gdb`. Prefer `snprintf` to `sprintf`. Use literal constant so `'-'` not `45`

Comment: ... but prefer `printf()` to either `snprintf()` or `sprintf()` in this case, and then skip the `write()` call altogether.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I guess that the OP's teacher forbids `printf`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `sprintf` and `snprintf` would probably be forbidden too in that case.

Comment: Not necessarily. Perhaps `stdout` is forbidden.

Comment: In the event that `printf()` is forbidden but `s`[`n`]`printf()` is not, `fputs()` or `puts()` would still be a better choice than `write()`.

Comment: I'm using sprintf() and write() just because every example program that we saw in class was written like this. Could you explain me what is bad at doing it please? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `i` is a global variable and therefore shared between `main` and `mi_atoi`. Every time you call `mi_atoi`, it resets `i`, so the loop in `main` never terminates.

You cleverly tried to hide the bug by not posting the declaration of `i` (let alone a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but we can see that `i` is not declared as a local variable in the functions you did post.